# Saving original label position in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

If I am generating line geometry with a marker to label parcels when I use a label call-out, (attached images) how can I use the automatically defined label placement point for my anchor?

[image]

QGIS draws my line to the centroid as soon as I move the label from it's original position.

Is there a variable that holds this original geometry position that QGIS put the label at?

Answer (score 2):

You can save all original label positions with the following recipe:
- add two colums (decimal) x and y to your data
- set the labelposition (label position tab) to datadefinded override (your fields x and y)
- now use the pinlabel tool to pin all labels (just press shift and select all with the rectangular select box)
- the coordinate colums x and y now have the coordinates of the original label positions.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not quite.  What you have suggested is the same essential procedure as just moving the label.  The coords of the label are saved the same way as pinning.  What I am trying to do is save the position of the label presently established by the placement engine so I can draw a leader to that position and move the text of the label someplace else on the map.

Comment: after my procedure described above, you should deactivate the datadefined override to the two fields (x and y in my case), because if not, if moving the labels the original position stored in the fields will be updated. and in fact, in that case it is like you described. Just make two new fields x2, y2 and store the moved positions there and making your callouts between (x,y) and (x2,y2)...that should do the trick